# Cast as Float returns ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I am doing the following in Rails `4.2.7`

`@product.reviews.select('CAST(answer_1 AS FLOAT) AS answer_1')`

Unfortunately this returns

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FLOAT) AS answer_1 FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviews`.`product_id` = 1' at line 1: 
SELECT CAST(answer_1 AS FLOAT) AS answer_1 
FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviews`.`product_id` = 1
```

Comment: Really, what I need to do is `AVG(CAST(answer_1 AS FLOAT)) AS answer_1` but I can't get the casting to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently MySQL's `cast` function doesn't understand `float` as a datatype. The [fine manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) tells you to look at [`convert`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) for the types and there is no `float` in the list.

MySQL's `cast` does however support `decimal(m,n)` but then you'll have to choose the appropriate scale and precision values yourself. Or you could use `cast(answer_1 as signed)` or `cast(answer_1 as unsigned)` if integers are appropriate.

If you're actually averaging and `answer_1` is already a number then you don't need to cast anything at as [`avg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) returns a floating point value on its (but the docs aren't explicit on this of course).

You could also run into some problems because your column alias:

```
avg(answer_1) as answer_1
```

has the same name as an existing column. ActiveRecord will probably get confused by the name and try to convert the average to whatever the `answer_1` column is. Using a different name should work better.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that doing `AVG(answer_1) AS answer_1` is returning a `Fixnum < Integer` via my query `@product.reviews.select('AVG(answer_1) AS answer_1')` but when I do a raw SQL query with AVG(`reviews`.`answer_1`) I get a float back.

Comment: That suggests that the `answer_1` column is an integer and that ActiveRecord is converting your `avg(answer_1) as answer_1` to a `Fixnum` because it thinks that anything called `answer_1` should be an integer. Try giving it a different alias in your `select` call.

Comment: Bingo. `.select('AVG(answer_1) AS foo')` gives me a float